# Formating %e output of sprintf

Tags: string, matlab, formatting, printf

Is it possible to format the output of `sprintf`, like following or should I use another function.

Say I have an variable `dt= 9.765625e-05` and I want use `sprintf` to make a string for use when saving say a figure

```
fig = figure(nfig);
plot(x,y);
figStr = sprintf('NS2d_dt%e',dt);
saveas(fig,figStr,'pdf')
```

The punctuation mark `dot` presents me with problems, some systems mistake the format of the file.

using

```
figStr = sprintf('NS2d_dt%.2e',dt);
```

then

```
figStr = NS2d_dt9.77e-05
```

using

```
figStr = sprintf('NS2d_dt%.e',dt);
```

then

```
figStr = NS2d_dt1e-04
```

which is not precise enough. I would like something like this
using

```
figStr = sprintf('NS2d_dt%{??}e',dt);
```

then

```
figStr = NS2d_dt9765e-08
```

Comment: Suggestion: Put a space in between the string and the number.  It's very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the only way to get your desired output is with some manipulation of the value or strings. So here's two solutions for you first with some string manipulation and second by manipulating the value. Hopefully, these 2 approaches will help reason out solutions for other problems, particularly the number manipulation.

## String Manipulation

### Solution

```
fmt = @(x) sprintf('%d%.0fe%03d', (sscanf(sprintf('%.4e', x), '%d.%de%d').' .* [1 0.1 1]) - [0 0.5 3]);
```

### Explanation

First I use `sprintf` to print the number in a defined format

```
>> sprintf('%.4e', dt)
ans =
    9.7656e-05
```

then `sscanf` to read it back in making sure to remove the `.` and `e`

```
>> sscanf(sprintf('%.4e', dt), '%d.%de%d').'
ans = 
    9    7656    -5
```

before printing it back we perform some manipulation of the data to get the correct values for printing

```
>> (sscanf(sprintf('%.4e', dt), '%d.%de%d').' .* [1 0.1 1]) - [0 0.5 3]
ans = 
    9    765.1    -8
```

and now we print

```
>> sprintf('%d%.0fe%03d', (sscanf(sprintf('%.4e', dt), '%d.%de%d').' .* [1 0.1 1]) - [0 0.5 3])
ans =
    9765e-08
```

---

## Number Manipulation

### Solution

```
orderof = @(x) floor(log10(abs(x)));
fmt = @(x) sprintf('%.0fe%03d', x*(10^(abs(orderof(x))+3))-0.5, orderof(x)-3);
```

### Explanation

First I create an anonymous `orderof` function which tells me the order (the number after `e`) of the input value. So

```
>> dt = 9.765625e-05;
>> orderof(dt)
ans =
    -5
```

Next we manipulate the number to convert it to a 4 digit integer, this is the effect of adding `3` in

```
>> floor(dt*(10^(abs(orderof(dt))+3)))
ans =
    9756
```

finally before printing the value we need to figure out the new exponent with

```
>> orderof(x)-3
ans =
    -8
```

and printing will give us

```
>> sprintf('%.0fe%03d', floor(dt*(10^(abs(orderof(dt))+3))), orderof(dt)-3)
ans =
    9765e-08
```

Answer (score 0):

```
figStr = sprintf('NS2d_dt%1.4e',dt)
figStr =
NS2d_dt9.7656e-05
```

specify the number (`1.4` here) as NumbersBeforeDecimal (dot) NumbersAfterDecimal.

Regarding your request:

```
A = num2str(dt);     %// convert to string
B = A([1 3 4 5]);    %// extract first four digits
C = A(end-2:end);    %// extract power
fspec = 'NS2d_dt%de%d'; %// format spec
sprintf(fspec ,str2num(B),str2num(C)-3)
NS2d_dt9765e-8
```

Comment: That don't help me, i want to shift the power, `9.765e-05` to `9765e-08`

Comment: 9765e-08 isn't standard

Comment: @MatthewGunn yes, that's the problem. If it were, there'd be an automatic option for it. It being this weird requires quite the work around.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question,

> The punctuation mark dot presents me with problems, some systems mistake the format of the file.

it seems to me that your actual problem is that when you build the file name using, for example

```
figStr = sprintf('NS2d_dt%.2e',dt);
```

you get

```
figStr = NS2d_dt9.77e-05
```

and, then, when you use that string as filename, the `.` is intepreted as the extension and the `.pdf` is not attached, so in `Explorer` you can not open the file double-clicking on it.

Considering that changing the representation of the number `dt` from `9.765e-05` to `9765e-08` seems quite wierd, you can try the following approach:

- use the `print` function to save your figure in `.pdf`
- add `.pdf` in the `format` specifier

This should allows you the either have the right file extension and the right format for the `dt` value.

```
peaks
figStr = sprintf('NS2d_dt_%.2e.pdf',dt);

print(gcf,'-dpdf', figStr )
```

Hope this helps.